# Vue child prop is not updated on bound value change in parent

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-props

I'm using vue-property-decorator lib. I've got 2 components: ***parent*** and ***child***, *child* is a component that has a prop **'modalHeader'**:

```ts
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
    name: "modal"
})
export default class Modal extends Vue {
    @Prop({default: "Header"}) public modalHeader!: string;
}
</script>
```

Child component's template:

```html
<template>
    <div
        class="modal fade"
        id="detailsModal"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="detailsModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
    >
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="detailsModalLabel">
                        {{ modalHeader }}
                    </h5>
                </div>
                ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I have a property **'buttonPressed'** in my ***parent*** component and I want to bind its properties to child prop, thus every time depending on the button pressed I'll get a different header for modal:

```ts
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Modal from '../modal/Modal.vue';

interface ControlButtonSetting {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    enabled: boolean,
    isDanger: boolean,
    okText?: string,
    componentType?: IModalComponent,
}

@Component({
    name: "admin-dashboards-page",
    components: {
        "modal": Modal
    }
})
export default class AdminDashboardsPage extends Vue {

    private buttonsArray: ControlButtonSetting[] = [
        { id: "removeButton", name: "Remove", enabled: false, isDanger: true, okText: "Remove" }
    ];

    public buttonPressed!: ControlButtonSetting;

    private showModal = false;

    created(): void {
        this.buttonPressed = this.buttonsArray[0];
    }

    public controlButtonClicked(button: ControlButtonSetting): void {
        this.buttonPressed = button;
        this.showModal = true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Parent component's template:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        ...

        <!-- Modal -->
        <modal
            :modal-header.sync="buttonPressed.name"
            <template v-slot:modalBody>
                <component
                    :is="displayComponent()"
                    :dashboard-id="selectedListItemId">
                </component>
            </template>
        </modal>
    </div>
</template>
```

However, the **'modalHeader'** value is set only once when the page loaded, but when **'selectedButton'** object is changed, **'modalHeader'** value is not being updated on the child component.

What helped me is to define ***parent's*** object as a `Prop()`:

```ts
@Prop() public buttonPressed!: ControlButtonSetting;
```

This way *child component's prop* is updated whenever *parent's prop* is updated. But I start to see this message in a console:

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "buttonPressed"
```

##### I'm not really sure what is wrong here. Could you help me with it?

P.S. One guess I have is that I'm not mutating bound property in parent but replacing it with a new object, that's why parent-child binding may not work. Gonna check it out.

Comment: Could you share the template of *parent* component? at least the part including the *child* component?

Comment: @Kapcash Yep. Adding it to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: your `buttonPressed` data isn't reactive because it is not initialised. It has to be properly initialised for Vue to mark it as reactive.

```js
public buttonPressed!: ControlButtonSetting; // not initialised
```

You have two options to initialise it properly:

#1 You give it a proper default value, even empty, directly after declaring it.

```js
public buttonPressed: ControlButtonSetting = {
  id: "",
  name: "",
  enabled: false,
  isDanger: false,
  okText: ""
}
```

#2 If you want its default value to rely on other data / props, use the `data` factory. (Don't use `created` hook for this)

```js
public buttonPressed!: ControlButtonSetting; // use !: to tell typescript it's declared but in another place

// Even using `vue-property-decorator`, this will work and merge both data() and class properties
data () {
  return {
     buttonPressed: this.buttonsArray[0],
  }
}
```

---

Don't mark `buttonPressed` as a prop, because it isn't. And a Vue prop can't be updated from childs, it would break the reactivity of the parent.

---

Note: Vue props should always have a type provided. Even using `vue-property-decorator`, you have to specify it.

```js
@Prop({ type: String, default: 'Header' }) <- Vue prop type, only for runtime
readonly modalHeader!: string // <- typescript type, only for build time
```

(I advise you to use `readonly` keyword to tell Typescript this property cannot be updated, because props are immutable in Vue)

Comment: Thank you. Setting the default value for bounded values helped me!